# Run already opened process in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, vb.net-2010

I have a windows form that, on the click of a button, runs a process (MATLAB) and executes a file.

```
    Dim myProcesses() As Process
    myProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName("Matlab")
    If myProcesses.Count > 0 Then
        '~~~~ what goes here? ~~~~
    Else
        Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo
        startInfo.FileName = "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2011b\bin\matlab.exe"
        startInfo.WorkingDirectory = MatlabDir    'MatlabDir is defined elsewhere
        startInfo.Arguments = "matlab.exe -r test_plot2"
        Process.Start(startInfo)
    End If
```

The above code opens MATLAB and executes the script "test_plot2.m" if MATLAB isn't already open.  But what do I write in the first IF statement, if MATLAB is already open, and all I want to do is run the file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe it's worth pointing out that MATLAB has a command based user interface i.e. if I want to run "test_plot2.m", all I do is type in "test_plot2" in the command window.

Answer (score 0):

Its supposed to be the same. I mean, it doesn't matter if its opened or not, unless the application (Matlab) manages something different, then you have to guess how. Have you tried just using the same code?

Example:

```
    Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo
    startInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe"
    startInfo.Arguments = "C:\temp\test.txt"
    Process.Start(startInfo)
```

It doesn't matter if you have Notepad already opened or not.

Comment: Yes, I tried using the same code, but it opens another MATLAB window.  This is a problem because not only is MATLAB quite a bulky application (takes a while to open), but we also have a limited number of licenses.  Looks like I'll have to play around a little more!  Thanks anyway!

Comment: There must be a code (argument) to use the method Matlab is using to open the new documents without opening a new window. Maybe try reading the documentation or asking to the company. Good luck!